Missile Impact Velocity
For the past 10 years or so I hear more and more about so called "Hypersonic Missiles" that can hit their targets at speeds exceeding Mach 10.
I wonder about the accuracy about such descriptions. There's no problem with flying at crazy high speeds outside of the atmosphere - but surely, doing so in the lower layers will cause enormous heat and melt down the vehicle.
For example, the SR-71 had to be built from special materials to allow it to fly at Mach 3.2 and even then only at very high altitudes.
Has our understanding of aerodynamics and material science changed so much since the times of the SR-71 ? Or the numbers are simply being thrown around by people who don't know any better ?

Heat is not the only challenge. Total or stagnation pressure increases faster with Mach than temperature. For example, at Mach 10 the ratio of total temperature to ambient is 21 whereas same for pressure is 42,439.  Or, another way to think of it is sea level qbar at M=10  is >1,000 psi, ~100x higher at M=10 than M=1. Drag increases dramatically in terminal phase.

I mean, at mach 10, you can hit a target 500 miles away in under 4 minutes, so being able to soak the heat for that long is a very different question from the SR-71 that wants to last for hours and return to base afterward.

You are correct about the heat problem. It is a major issue with hypersonic air-breathing vehicles operating within the atmosphere or spacecraft returning to Earth at orbital velocities. The choice of materials to construct a vehicle with is largely based on the heating it experiences in certain areas of the airframe. In general, the vehicle will get extremely hot on the nose and leading edges of the wings and control surfaces. Other areas are not as heat critical, so less exotic solutions will be require required in these locations.
Another issue is time, i.e. the length of time that the vehicle experiences hypersonic flight and the rate at which the air frame becomes heat soaked. Simple hypersonic missiles which maintain these kinds of speeds and temperatures for short periods of flight can make do with relatively simple thermal protection systems, whereas an aircraft or a spacecraft intended to spend a great deal of time at these speeds and having the air frame thoroughly heat soaked requires more exotic and expensive solutions.
To date these issues have been addressed with a number of different solutions in creating a thermal protection system (TPS):

Exotic metallic and composite materials - Build the exterior of your craft out of exotic heat resistant materials. The SR-71 Blackbird which you cited above was constructed largely out of titanium for this reason. The MiG-25 opted for a relatively economical, albeit heavy, solution of manufacturing the airframe out of stainless steel. The X-15 research aircraft which achieved speeds of Mach 6 was constructed largely of Inconel. The X-43 hypersonic research aircraft used a leading edge made from carbon-carbon composite.

Ceramic based TPS - This has been a very popular solution for exo-atmospheric vehicles entering the atmosphere at orbital or near-orbital velocities. First pioneered on the space shuttle, it consists of affixing a mosaic of ceramic tiles to the outside of the craft, generally on the bottom surface and other heat critical areas, to provide excellent thermal insulation and heat protection during reentry.  A chief difficulty with these designs has been preventing tiles from being shaken loose with the stresses encountered during launch. This has been a problem for even modern applications like SpaceX’s Starship.

Ablative TPS Materials - These are materials designed to burn off and dissipate the heat encountered during hypersonic flight for brief periods. The X-15 program use the solution of a spray-on cork slurry covering the exterior of the aircraft, which provided limited thermal protection during hypersonic flight.

Boundary layer cooling - common in modern jet engines, the technique requires drilling a mosaic of fine holes in the surface of a part subject to high temperatures, and passing cool air through these, effectively creating a colder boundary layer than the high temperature air in free stream, thus protecting the part.

Vehicle Shaping - One of the best ways to reduce structural heating is to design a vehicle that transfers most of the frictional heating into the atmosphere as opposed to the airframe.  It was found through experiments in the 1950s that blunt shapes work far better than sleek or needle like shapes in order to do that. This is why most hypersonic aircraft or lifting body spacecraft employee a wedge-shaped fuselage which has the additional benefit of serving is a lifting body for either glide or powered flight in the atmosphere when re-entry is complete.  Other examples are cone shaped space capsule designs with heat shields on the base of the capsule.  This was a default with the Mercury, Gemini, and Apollo programs.  Most recently, Boeing’s StarLiner program and SpaceX’s Dragon space capsules make use of this re-entry philosophy for thermal protection.



i would imagine that single use would free up some design considerations that would be concerned with durability.

So an impact velocity of Mach 10 is attainable ?

@shaiko - a look at the Sprint Missile may be informative of what is physically possible, and what size it ends up being. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprint_(missile).

There's also perspiration cooling, where you force coolant out through holes in the skin and the boiling coolant is swept away by the airstream to get rid of the heat.

Early reentry bodies used a large copper tip as a heat sink.

@ Peter Kämpf what vehicles use that?
